# Require filling out or giving an empty field alert for a form field before scrolling or clicking a "next" button in a multi-part form?

Tags: forms, scroll, tags, required

I'm building a multi-part form that is actually all on one page, it just uses anchors to give the illusion of multiple pages. Users click a link to continue to the next segment.

I am looking for a way to have an alert to fill in certain fields before clicking the next button or possibly by scrolling past a certain point. The next button is just a link and not a submit button, thus all the billions of times this has been asked before on the Internet don't apply here.

I am just looking for a soft-required, it doesn't have to actually force them to do it. And the reason I can't really do required on submitting fields in this form is that all of the unique segments and a user might never see a segment that has a required field based on their inputs. Not to mention it would be a pain to go back in a 20 step form to find the field you left blank.

It's not critical that they are filled out, just looking to give a heads-up to the users.

Comment: You could try what this site is suggesting https://www.sitepoint.com/instant-validation/

Answer (score 0):

It is a little confusing regarding exactly what you are wishing to do, but I would use javascript to create this.

1. Add a listener to the prev/next buttons calling a function when they are clicked.
2. In this function, check each input on the page to see if they are empty.
3. If they are empty, somehow explain to the user that they are empty (using an alert popup or some sort of css change)
4. You can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the user from navigating to the next page.

Let me know if you have any questions, I am explaining the process I believe you should follow.

Comment: That sounds like what I need although lets say there's 20 anchors and the visitor only sees one anchor at a time. Wouldn't this solution alert the user to an empty field in an anchor segment that they haven't seen yet? In other words, won't it be looking for all of the blank fields on the entire form when you click the next button.

Comment: Good question, I am sure each page's fields are in a "container" which you may be able to target with your javascript. You will just need to get specific with the javascript selectors, adding more classes to the markup if needed.